# What are the advantage of using RequestsClient() over APIClient()?

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am writing unittest for Django-rest-framework API endpoints. In [version 3.5](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.5-announcement/#requests-test-client), they have added RequestsClient(). Documentation says -

> Rather than sending any HTTP requests to the network, this interface will coerce all outgoing requests into WSGI, and call into your application directly.

From my understanding, I think RequestsClient() is useful for the network request from different servers. Not sure if it has any advantage in the same server? Also Is there any advantage of using RequestsClient() over APIClient() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not sure, use the standard `APIClient`.

`RequestsClient` is useful if either:

1. You intend to most be interacting with the API from another Python service and want your tests to work at the same level.
2. You want to write tests in a way that allows you to also run them against a live or staging environment.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any advantage of using RequestsClient() over APIClient()

This is a higher lever of test. `RequestsClient` will test against your stack from the WSGI layer which APIClient bypasses.
This also means that tests that uses authentication or CSRF will be looking more like what happens with real requests.